# Youtube-Videos embedded with iframe often won't play in iPhone's Safari

Tags: iphone, html, iframe, youtube

I created a webpage which offers some tutorial videos for an iPhone-app of mine. I've uploaded the videos to youtube and used the default iframe-based embed-code supplied by youtube to embed them into the page. The problem is, that if I visit the page with my iPhone (4S, iOS 5.0.1) and try to watch the videos, they often don't start and I just get a black frame. Sometimes they play, but most of the time they don't. What is the problem here? How can I fix it?

This is the page I'm talking about, so you can test it yourself and check the html-code (if you can watch them, please try to reload the page and try again, because as I said, sometimes it works):
http://aremac.viarum.com/help.php

Answer (score 2):

Movies do load on my iPhne 4 using latest iOS. But there are several html errors (invalid markup issues) that might be the cause of the loading issue. See http://validator.w3.org/ and check. The page is XHMTL 1.0 transitional and there are 5 errors. The allowfullscreen attribute is a YouTube only attribute. I would remove it and see if that helps improving the loading of the video in the iframe. There are also some other errors, but I do not think that they are related or are part of the issue. Would be good to remmove those as well though. Should not be to hard with the hints given.

Comment: Ok, I corrected the errors (including removing the "allowfullscreen" attributes), but the videos still won't play reliably on my iPhone. (Also a friend told me, that they don't play on his iPhone, so it's definitively not just a problem with mine.)

Comment: Try embedding without the iframe just using the object embed code. Should work better in iOS. See also http://vzaar.com/help/kb/features/what-are-the-differences-between-the-iframe-and-object-embed-codes and http://help.vzaar.com/help/kb/video-and-technical-questions/vzaar-embed-code-for-ios-5-playback